# iOS - Horizontal UIScrollView with multiple UITableViews

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

`UIScrollView` scrolls Horizontally and `UITableView` scrolls vertically inside that but unable to load different data when scroll horizontally.

have one scrollview which scrolls horizontally on screen and inside of that i have added multiple tableview and want to display different different datas on tableview when swipe. i have tried this but with no luck :(

```
NSArray *arr1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];
NSArray *arr2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"4",@"5",@"6", nil];
NSArray *arr3 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"7",@"8",@"9", nil];
NSArray *arr4 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"10",@"11",@"12", nil];
arrData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:arr1,arr2,arr3,arr4, nil];

int width=0;

for (int i = 0; i<[arrData count]; i++) {
    tblData = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(width, 20, 300, 245) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tblData.dataSource = self;
    tblData.delegate = self;
    [tblData setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    tblData.separatorColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [scrHorizontal addSubview:tblData];
    width+=300;
}

[self.scrHorizontal setContentSize:CGSizeMake(([arrData count])*300, self.scrHorizontal.frame.size.height)];
```

here 4 pages inside scrollview which includes 4 tableviews i want to display 1,2,3 on first table and 4,5,6 on second table when swipe scrollview and so on...

please help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen your code , you can do with `tag`,

1. set tag to tableview in loop

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i<[arrData count]; i++) {
   tblData = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(width, 20, 300, 245) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

   tblData.tag=i;
   tblData.dataSource = self;
   tblData.delegate = self;
   [tblData setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
   tblData.separatorColor = [UIColor blackColor];
   [scrHorizontal addSubview:tblData];
   width+=300;
   }
   ```

now in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** method just use it
like

```
NSArray *arr = [arrData objectAtIndex:tableView.tag];
cell.textLabel.text = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

check it [ScrollViewDemo](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0AGzQqxBZ9CUXZuMG83MFg3b28/edit?usp=sharing)

Hope it Helps.

Comment: +1, i have tried with tag before but didn't used it properly thanks for the help man :) it works perfect!